# setOnFocusChangeListener not called on EditText when changing tabs

Tags: android

I have an app with 5 tabs using a ViewPager. Tab 3 has an EditText field, so the user enters text using the soft keyboard. I added a setOnFocusChangeListener to hide the keyboard once the focus of the EditText is lost:

```
    versesEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.edittext_chew_verses && !hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    });
```

When the user is done with entering text and switches to another tab, the Listener is called and the keyboard disappear (so far everything works well). The strange thing is, the Listener is **not called once the user switches to the tab on the left side.** The Listener is called as expected once Tabs 1, 4, or 5 are selected, but it is **NOT CALLED** once Tab 2 is selected (see attached screenshot). This is my EditText:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_chew_verses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/chew_hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Any idea? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWt3g.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ViewPager.onPageChangeListener:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is page is not tab 3 and hide the soft keyboard
    }
});
```

Edit 1: (First comment)

You can use this function to hide soft keyboard without editText:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        view.clearFocus();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the instance of the EditText in order to hide the keyboard in it. I don't have that instance yet at the time I setup the viewpager.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example on how to hide a softkeyboard without EditText. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, do you by any chance know why tab #2 did not hide the keyboard while all others did??

Comment: Maybe tab 2 didn't have a view to take the focus away from EditText. Can't really say for sure. Good luck!